# Enter press event for vaadin 10 TextField

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

Is there any specific way to add shortcut Listener for the Enter Key on a specific TextField element in Vaadin Flow. The documentation is silent about this.

Comment: Do you care about that particular keystroke, or detecting the user has completed data-entry in that field?

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are not actually looking for a ”shortcut” key but to react to enter presses when the focus is inside the field? If so, see KeyNotifier and e.g. addKeyPressListener.

It is also possible to listen to any DOM event using the element API, e.g.

```
textField.getElement().addEventListener("keyup", e -> { 
    System.out.println("Value is now: " + 
        e.getEventData().getString("element.value"));
}).addEventData("element.value").setFilter("event.keyCode == 13");
```

Comment: I'd recommend making the code more readable through filtering by `event.key = 'Enter'` instead of using obscure key codes.

Answer (score 3):

In the [Vaadin Directory](https://vaadin.com/directory) there is a UI Web Component for Vaadin 10. It's called [shortcut](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/shortcut). The usage is very simple:

```
Shortcut.add(messageField, Key.ENTER, sendButton::click);
```

You also can also add modifier keys like that:

```
Shortcut.add(messageField, Key.ENTER, sendButton::click, Key.SHIFT);
```

Comment: Does this work with a `TextField` as well as a button? The Question was not about buttons.